# Limit Mysql need to return n% of random records from table

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

completely stuck use different approaches but still no luck,
I am using MySQl and SparkSql 
I have simple select

```
SELECT 
rdw.merchant_id, hash_id, transaction_ts 
FROM table_1 rdw
JOIN table_2 bl ON rdw.MERCHANT_ID = bl.MERCHANT_ID
WHERE brand = 'TBrand'
order by rand()
limit 36
```

and this  is perfectly work, but here is the problem in `limit 36` i need select 30 % from all records, I cannot pass number in it because spark failed on working with variables. I . trying to calculate  % in limit but . its now alowed, any ideas how to load ?
Problem is, I dont know how many records will be returned by select, thats why i cannot set limit, it should be %  from records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can deal with an *approximate* 30%, you can simply do:

```
where brand = 'TBrand' and rand() <= 0.3
```

If you want a better approximation to 30%, then you can do:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT rdw.merchant_id, hash_id, transaction_ts,
             (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM table_1 rdw JOIN
           table_2 bl
           ON rdw.MERCHANT_ID = bl.MERCHANT_ID CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      WHERE brand = 'TBrand'
      ORDER BY rand()
     ) x
WHERE rn <= @rn * 0.30
```

Comment: the problem is that . every single run query return different numbers of records , 1st run its 172 , 2nd 200, 3rd 282 . so this solution is not working  properly

Comment: @Andrey . . . Why is that a problem?  You are asking for a random sample and that is how random samples work.  If you want a repeatable random sample, I would really suggest that you ask another question.  The two are rather different.

Comment: Yes it is returning random records but  i need random 30% of all records  but its returning sometimes more 30% of random records some times less than 30% , but i need its to be 30%

Comment: @Andrey . . . That is what "approximate" means in the answer.

Comment: :) ok , but thanx anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @row_number = 0;
select merchant_id, hash_id, transaction_ts  
from (
 SELECT 
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as num,
rdw.merchant_id, hash_id, transaction_ts 
FROM table_1 rdw
JOIN table_2 bl ON rdw.MERCHANT_ID = bl.MERCHANT_ID
WHERE brand = 'TBrand'
order by rand()
) 
where num <= FLOOR((@row_number * 3) /10  )
```

Comment: its . working in MySql i need to check if it will work with SparkSQL  which . is failed with my . previous attempts